# Dictionary keys and value pair swap themselves

Tags: python

```
import time

sector = 100

dict = {
     0: {"sector1": '', 'time': ''},
     1: {"sector2": '', 'time': ''}
     }

for index in range(2):     
    dict[index].update({'sector'+str(index+1): sector, 'time': time.perf_counter()})
    sector += 100


print(dict)
```

I have this code above which unexpectedly I saw that dictionary keys and value are being swapped randomly or should I say frequently.

Here is what I mean

```
{
0: {'sector1': 100, 'time': 80069.410857487}, 
1: {'sector2': 200, 'time': 80069.410862547}
}
```

The above output is the expected result

```
{
0: {'time': 79298.567438224, 'sector1': 100}, 
1: {'time': 79298.567442553, 'sector2': 200}
}
```

but I will get the output above randomly

what is the cause? and does it have any underlying issues if my dict will have a lot of data?

Answer (score 2):

Python `dict`s are unordered, so the internal storage may be in any order. If you would like an ordered dictionary, use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: I see, you will always learn new things when new to a language.